# Jquery ajax calls to a number of pages very slow

Tags: jquery

Not sure if my logic here is out of whack, or it's just the nature of ajax. I'll try to explain. I've got a page that pulls a bit of information (text contained in a div with the id of preamble), and then appends it to divs on the current page.

This is the page:
http://www.cresser.co.uk/cresser/new-cars/

The function isn't fired until the page fully loads, which I know causes a further delay, which I'm looking into.

But as you'll see it's the red text that appears with in the vehicle model boxes. Very slow.

This is the code, and like I say, I might be doing it totally illogically.

```
$('.indexList .item').each(function(){

var tempPath = $(this).attr('class').replace('item ', '').replace(' myPointer', '');

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            url:  './' + tempPath,
            success: function(data) {
                $(data).find('#preamble').each(function(){
                $('.item.' + tempPath + ' .strapLine').append($(this).text());
                $('.item.' + tempPath + ' .strapLine').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Is it just that what I'm trying to do is stupid using ajax, or is there a way to speed up this code?

Thanks.

Edit. Just to clarify, it's not the load speed of the whole page I'm bothered about... at the moment. It's the speed of the function that loads the red text. IE. The time the first one appears to when the last one appears just seems very long to me.

Comment: `$(data).find('#preamble').each(` ids should be unique.

Comment: They are. This is just to find the text contained in the #preamble div on the external pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching **11 different HTML pages** using AJAX and each one is clocking between **5 and 11 seconds** considering blockings (with my connection.) If you are planning to use AJAX it is better if you use it with a *lightweight* web service. That is, create a web service that returns only the relevant information using JSON instead of HTML.

I'm afraid your bottleneck is there.

Comment: This might be the sort of sanity check I need. I'm guessing this is not such a good plan after all :)

Comment: You need to reduce the number of requests to a minimum. This page will take ages to load in really bad connection situations

Answer (score 1):

Rather than firing an ajax call to the page for each car why don't you fire one ajax call and get all the car info and then use jquery to add the data to the dom.

That way you will only have one 10s+ delay.

Although I'd question why it's taking 10s to get a response from that page. I'd guess its the serverside code that's causing the issue. Is the DB huge? Have you timed your DB queries?

As far as the ajax is concerned its fine. If the serverside code was quick your page would load the info much quicker even if making 100 ajax calls.

Comment: Yeah. We have got an issue with the serverside code which drives the mini selector up the top left. But that is being looked into. So you don't see a problem loading info from 11 separate HTML pages?

Comment: Are you not able to make just one call for all the information and return a json array. Then iterate over this array and add the red text?

Overall though 11 ajax calls wont end the world if the code its calling is quick.

Can you make the call to another page? And are you bypassing the majority of the serverside code if the request is being made by ajax. No point on the ajax call having to wait on things that don't affect what it's going to return.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't look after the actual page content, hence the reason I'm having to take this roundabout way of doing things. It's not crucial to the site, or indeed this page. IT's just a flourish, and if needs be I'll knock it on the head. Just want to see if there was a quicker way of doing it, even though the data is split over a number of external pages. Not to worry. Thanks.